# Is there a way to protect Unit test names that follows MethodName_Condition_ExpectedBehaviour pattern against refactoring?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, resharper

I follow the naming convention of

> **MethodName_Condition_ExpectedBehaviour**

when it comes to naming my unit-tests that test specific methods.

for example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetCity_TakesParidId_ReturnsParis(){...}
```

But when I need to rename the method under test, tools like ReSharper does not offer me to rename those tests.

Is there a way to prevent such cases to appear after renaming? Like changing ReSharper settings or following a better unit-test naming convention etc. ?

Comment: How is this related to Java? The `java` tag should be removed from among the tags. Anyway, in Java (with JUnit for example) if you write a test for a specific method then there will no connection between the test and the method under test and Eclipse, NetBeans, etc. won't offer you to refactor the test method's name. I can't comment on ReSharper's behaviour.

Comment: Is 'Changing the method name' a big use-case for you ? If it is.. maybe you can omit this change-magnet from your test names. E.g. [class] TestCityRepository has test-method ShouldRetrieveCityById. This way you're isolated from the implementation method name..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A recent pattern is to groups tests into inner classes by the method they test.

For example (omitting test attributes):

```
public CityGetterTests 
{
   public class GetCity
   {
      public void TakesParidId_ReturnsParis()
      {
          //...
      }

      // More GetCity tests
   }
}
```

See [Structuring Unit Tests from Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/02/structuring-unit-tests.aspx) for details.

The neat thing about this layout is that, when the method name changes,
you'll only have to change the name of the inner class instead of all 
the individual tests.

Comment: I really like the idea! Where have you learnt about this pattern by the way? Any resource or an article or... ? (Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

I also started with this convertion, however ended up with feeling that is not very good. Now I use BDD styled names like `should_return_Paris_for_ParisID`.

That makes my tests more readable and alsow allows me to refactor method names without worrying about my tests :)

Comment: So you do not mention the name of the method in the unit-test name at all?

Comment: no, that allows me to rename it later without any sideeffects :) I think that I test scenarios, not particular methods

Comment: Maybe your way can be connected with a comment like : Method In Test : GetCity . So that ReSharper will offer to renamt this TEXT when you are renaming your method.

Comment: Maybe, but again, I think that method name is not essential.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is what you *should* be testing.

You've mentioned TDD in the tags, so I hope that we're trying to adhere to that here. By that paradigm, the tests you're writing have two purposes:

1. To **support your code** once it is written, so you can refactor without fearing that you've broken something
2. To **guide us to a better way of designing components** - writing the test first really forces you to think about what is necessary for solving the problem at hand.

I know at first it looks like this question is about the first point, but really I think it's about the second. The problem you're having is that you've got concrete components you're testing instead of a contract.

In code terms, that means that I think we should be testing interfaces instead of class methods, because otherwise we expose our test to a variety of problems associated with testing **components** instead of **contracts** - inheritance strategies, object construction, and here, renaming.

It's true that interfaces names will change as well, but they'll be a lot more rigid than method names. What TDD gives us here isn't just a way to support change through a test harness - it provides the insight to realise we might be going about it the wrong way!

Take for example the code block you gave:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetCity_TakesParidId_ReturnsParis(){...}
{
    // some test logic here
}
```

And let's say we're testing the method **GetCity()** on our object, **CityObtainer** - when did I set this object up? Why have I done so? If I realise **GetMatchingCity()** is a better name, then you have the problem outlined above!

The solution I'm proposing is that we think about what this method really means *earlier* in the process, by use of interfaces:

```
public interface ICityObtainer
{
    public City GetMatchingCity();
}
```

By writing in this "outside-in" style way, we're forced to think about what we want from the object a lot earlier in the process, and it becoming the focus should reduce its volatility. This doesn't eliminate your problem, but it may mitigate it somewhat (and, I think, it's a better approach anyway).

Ideally, we go a step further, and we *don't even write any code* before starting the test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetCity_TakesParId_ReturnsParis
{
    ICityObtainer cityObtainer = new CityObtainer();
    var result = cityObtainer.GetCity("paris");

    Assert.That(result.Name, Is.EqualTo("paris");
}
```

This way, I can see what I really *want* from the component before I even start writing it - if **GetCity()** isn't really what I want, but rather **GetCityByID()**, it would become apparent a lot earlier in the process. As I said above, it isn't foolproof, but it might reduce the pain for this particular case a bit.

Once you've gone through that, I feel that if you're changing the name of the method, it's because you're *changing the terms of the contract*, and that means you **should** have to go back and reconsider the test (since it's possible you didn't want to change it).

(As a quick addendum, if we're writing a test with TDD in mind, then something is happening inside **GetCity()** that has a significant amount of logic going on. Thinking about the test as being to a contract helps us to separate the intention from the implementation - the test will stay valid *no matter what we change behind the interface*!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but maybe that Can be still useful. That's my solution (Assuming you are using XUnit at least).

First create an attribute FactFor that extends the XUnit Fact.

```
public class FactForAttribute : FactAttribute
{
    public FactForAttribute(string methodName = "Constructor", [CallerMemberName] string testMethodName = "")
        => DisplayName = $"{methodName}_{testMethodName}";
}
```

The trick now is to use the nameof operator to make refactoring possible. For example:

```
public class A
{
    public int Just2() => 2;
}

public class ATests
{
    [FactFor(nameof(A.Just2))]
    public void Should_Return2()
    {
        var a = new A();
        a.Just2().Should().Be(2);
    }
}
```

That's the result:

[image]